# Is there a way to list all C preprocessor defines?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Is there a way to list all C preprocessor defines?

I'm on a mac with a compiled from source gcc and

```
#if defined __APPLE__
#error "Apple"
#else
#error "Ahh"
#endif
```

is giving me:

```
error: #error "Ahh"
```

my compile configure options are:

```
${PWD}/../gcc/configure --prefix="${PWD}/../build/" --exec-prefix="${PWD}/../build/" --datadir="${PWD}/../build/" --target=avr --enable-languages=c --disable-libssp --disable-lto --disable-nls --disable-libgomp --disable-gdbtk --disable-threads --enable-poison-system-directories
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using gnu cpp, you can pass the option `-dM` to emit all defined macros.  That is:

```
$ cpp -dM foo.c
```

will tell you everything that is defined for foo.c.  There will be extra defines passed on the command line by make, and probably more things in config.h, but if you grab the output of make and rerun the commands with `-Xpreprocessor -dM` added you should see everything.

Comment: arg, This works but there is nothing defined to tell me i'm on a mac :(

Comment: It's also possible to do `cpp -dM </dev/null` without any source files. On some systems, GNU cpp is installed as `gcpp`.

Comment: When using the compiler main executable, such as `gcc` or `clang`, `-E -dM` will handily emit all preprocessor definitions to stdout.

Comment: @Justin808 You rally shouldn't care which platform you are on.  Test for features instead.  That is, if you want to know that you are on a mac because you intend to include `util.h` instead of including `pty.h` and/or `utmp.h`, you should instead setup your configure script to determine which headers are needed.

Comment: It is not documented, but `-E -dM` works with `tcc` as well.